# Append constant string to TargetName when building list of projects?

Tags: msbuild

I have a .proj file that contains a list of c++ project files and a couple of targets that builds the projects with different preprocessor macros, like so:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MyProjectItems Include="$(SourceDir)\Project1\Project1.vcxproj"/>
  <MyProjectItems Include="$(SourceDir)\Project2\Project2.vcxproj"/>
  <MyProjectItems Include="$(SourceDir)\Project3\Project3.vcxproj"/>
  <MyProjectItems Include="$(SourceDir)\Project4\Project4.vcxproj"/>
  <MyProjectItems Include="$(SourceDir)\Project5\Project5.vcxproj"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="NormalConfiguration">
  <MSBuild Projects="@(MyProjectItems)" 
         Targets="$(BuildTarget)"
         Properties="Configuration=Release;Platform=x86;/>
</Target>


<Target Name="SpecialConfigurationTarget">
  <MSBuild Projects="@(MyProjectItems)" 
         Targets="$(BuildTarget)"
         Properties="Configuration=Release;Platform=x86;SpecialConfiguration=SPECIAL_CONFIGURATION;TargetName=$(ProjectName)_SpecialConfiguration"/>
</Target>
```

The `NormalConfiguration` target works as expected.  Run that target and the output folder contains

```
Project1.exe
Project2.exe
Project3.exe
Project4.exe
Project5.exe
```

What I'm trying to do is append the string "_SpecialConfiguration" to the executable name when the `SpecialConfigurationTarget` is run.  So after running the `SpecialConfigurationTarget`, the output folder contains

```
Project1_SpecialConfiguration.exe
Project2_SpecialConfiguration.exe
Project3_SpecialConfiguration.exe
Project4_SpecialConfiguration.exe
Project5_SpecialConfiguration.exe
```

The above `SpecialConfigurationTarget` builds all of the `MyProjectItems`, but uses "_SpecialConfiguration.exe" as the output name.  So after running the `SpecialConfigurationTarget`, the output folder only contains

```
 _SpeicalConfiguration.exe
```

How can I get the name of the current project being build inside of an MSBuild task when that task is building multiple projects?